# Error 800A138F in download jquery-1.12.0.min.js

Tags: jquery, download

I'm trying to download jquery-1.12.0.min.js but get this error:

Line: 2
Char: 7509
Error: 'n' is null or not an object
Code: 800A138F
Source: Microsoft JScript runtime error

How do i resolve that problem?

Comment: Wat do u mean by _I am trying to download_?

Comment: i can't download 'cous this error msg

Comment: R u using a download manager?? I think u should add some more details to ur question

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Everything OK. I thought that i need to run this file that i load. But it turned out that there is no installation. Just to write the path to this file at the HTML doc and that's it.